# JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of... rest API in androidstudio

Tags: java, json, android-studio, jackson

I'm trying to implement the [global magnet API](https://globalmagnet.amentum.space/api/ui/#!/Click32to32view32documentation32for32API32endpoints/app_api_endpoints_GeoMag_calculate_magnetic_field) in an android application. I do a rest API get request and put the json API data in a `string` (this string is called `dataString`. This string looks like this:

```
{
  declination: {
  units: "Deg",
  value: -4.8235602378845215
  },
  inclination: {
  units: "Deg",
  value: -30.085556030273438
  },
  total_intensity: {
  units: "nT",
  value: 31945.123046875
  }
}
```

I'm now trying to deserialize this string into an object. I've made the following classes:

```
    public class MagneticData {
        @JsonProperty("declination")
        public MagneticDataElement declination;
        @JsonProperty("grid_variation")
        public MagneticDataElement grid_variation;
        @JsonProperty("inclination")
        public MagneticDataElement inclination;
        @JsonProperty("total_intensity")
        public MagneticDataElement total_intensity;
    }

    public class MagneticDataElement {
        @JsonProperty("units")
        public String units;
        @JsonProperty("value")
        public double value;
    }
```

I now use the `ObjectMapper.readValue()` function to convert the `dataString` to an object of the type `MagneticData` but i get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.mobcom.apitest.MainActivity$MagneticData: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show your `POJO` classes like you really have them in a project: with all getters, setters and constructors? Exception message is pretty clear: `missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?` means you do not have any public non argument constructor, or any other constructor which can be mapped to `JSON` easily.

Comment: Your `dataString` is not a valid JSON string because all the keys must be wrapped by double quotes and you don't have to add `@JsonProperty` to each field if the variable name and the key name of JSON object are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with revised JSON string and add `toString()` to your POJOs, everything works fine as follows, so maybe you have to provide more information for debugging such as how you deserialize it and which version of `Jackson` library you used.

**Revised JSON string**

```
{
  "declination": {
    "units": "Deg",
    "value": -4.8235602378845215
  },
  "inclination": {
    "units": "Deg",
    "value": -30.085556030273438
  },
  "total_intensity": {
    "units": "nT",
    "value": 31945.123046875
  }
}
```

**Code snippet**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MagneticData magneticData = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, MagneticData.class);
System.out.println(magneticData.toString());
```

**Console output**

> MagneticData [declination=MagneticDataElement [units=Deg, value=-4.8235602378845215], inclination=MagneticDataElement [units=Deg, value=-30.085556030273438], total_intensity=MagneticDataElement [units=nT, value=31945.123046875]]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jackson version 2.8.5:

```
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5'
```

This is my full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button click;
    TextView data;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonPropertyOrder({
            "units",
            "value"
    })

    public class MagneticData {
        @JsonProperty("declination")
        public MagneticDataElement declination;
        @JsonProperty("grid_variation")
        public MagneticDataElement grid_variation;
        @JsonProperty("inclination")
        public MagneticDataElement inclination;
        @JsonProperty("total_intensity")
        public MagneticDataElement total_intensity;

        MagneticData(MagneticDataElement d, MagneticDataElement g, MagneticDataElement i, MagneticDataElement t) {
            declination = d;
            grid_variation = g;
            inclination = i;
            total_intensity = t;
        }
    }

    public class MagneticDataElement {
        @JsonProperty("units")
        public String units;
        @JsonProperty("value")
        public double value;

        MagneticDataElement(String u, double v) {
            units = u;
            value = v;
        }
    }


    public void deserialize(String str) throws IOException {

        //data.setText(jsonNode.get("total_intensity").textValue());
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        click = findViewById(R.id.button);
        data = findViewById(R.id.fetchedData);

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String dataString = "";
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        double altitude = 0;
                        double latitude = 0;
                        double longitude = 0;
                        double year = 2019;
                        URL url = null;
                        try {
                            url = new URL("https://globalmagnet.amentum.space/api/calculate_magnetic_field?altitude="+altitude+"&latitude="+latitude+"&longitude="+longitude+"&year="+year);
                            HttpsURLConnection myConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            myConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                            myConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                            if (myConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                                Log.e("TYPE", myConnection.getContentType());
                                Log.e("Content", String.valueOf(myConnection.getInputStream()));
                                InputStream inputStream = myConnection.getInputStream();
                                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                                String line = "";
                                while (line != null) {
                                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                                    dataString = dataString + line;
                                }
                                Log.e("DATA", dataString);
                                MagneticData magneticData = new ObjectMapper().readValue(dataString, MagneticData.class);

                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                    }
                                });

                            } else {
                                Log.e("ERROR", String.valueOf(myConnection.getResponseCode()));
                                Log.e("ERROR", myConnection.getResponseMessage());
                                Log.e("ERROR", String.valueOf(myConnection.getHeaderField("altitude")));

                            }
                        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });



    }
}
```